# use dynamic snippet in Visual Studio 2008 Add-in

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

it`s possible to create snippet into StringBuilder/MemoryStream or something else and to use it?  More important:  without to create snippet files on hard disk in Visual Studio folder ( ...\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#)
I can do it? and how?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If just a bit of code you want to hand, you can drag to the toolbar and then use from there.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible in Visual Studio to provide an in memory snippets.  All snippets are loaded off of disk from the standard locations.